# Creating a list from specific elements of a dictionary

Tags: python, list

Hi the code that I have been given from my assignment is

```
legislators = { "Tsang Yok-sing" : "DAB", "Albert Ho" : "Democratic", "Lee Cheuk-yan" : "Labour", "James To" : "Democratic", "Chan Kam-lam" : "DAB", "Lau Wong-fat" : "Economic Synergy", "Emily Lau" : "Democratic" }
```

I need to create two lists, one with only the legislators names and the other with the list of parties. I don't understand what the colons in between the list means, I am guessing it connects the two somehow. Really appreciate some guidance.

Appreciate ya Papa love

Sorry for my mistake, this is a dictionary as people have mentioned. New to Python

Comment: This is not a list, this is a dictionary. The colons means a key --> value relationship between the elements

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks I will look into that on Google!

Comment: its a dictionary with key:Value pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `legislators` is a `dict` not a `list`. You could access to `keys` and `values`:

```
names = list(legislators.keys())
parties = list(legislators.values())

print(names)
['Tsang Yok-sing', 'Lee Cheuk-yan', 'James To', 'Chan Kam-lam', 'Lau Wong-fat', 'Emily Lau', 'Albert Ho']

print(parties)
['DAB', 'Labour', 'Democratic', 'DAB', 'Economic Synergy', 'Democratic', 'Democratic']
```

*Note* You need to call `list` to `legislators.keys` only if you have python `3.x`. For python `2.x` it's not necessary.

**EDIT**

As @Frerich Raabe suggested in the comment you could use `set` to get unique parties like:

```
parties = set(legislators.values())

print(parties)
{'DAB', 'Democratic', 'Economic Synergy', 'Labour'}
```

Or if you want list as the result:

```
print(list(set(legislators.values())))
['Democratic', 'Labour', 'Economic Synergy', 'DAB']
```

Comment: You might want to use `set()` instead of `list()` to get rid of duplicates in `parties`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe yeah, if the OP interested in the unique values it could be done with `set`

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a dictionary.

You could split it into two list like this:

```
legislators = { "Tsang Yok-sing" : "DAB", "Albert Ho" : "Democratic", "Lee Cheuk-yan" : "Labour", "James To" : "Democratic", "Chan Kam-lam" : "DAB", "Lau Wong-fat" : "Economic Synergy", "Emily Lau" : "Democratic" }

names = []
parties = []

for item in legislators:
    names.append(item)
    parties.append(legislators[item])

print names, parties
```

Will result in

```
['Tsang Yok-sing', 'Emily Lau', 'Lau Wong-fat', 'Chan Kam-lam', 'James To', 'Albert Ho', 'Lee Cheuk-yan']
['DAB', 'Democratic', 'Economic Synergy', 'DAB', 'Democratic', 'Democratic', 'Labour']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy oneliner using `zip(*legislators.items())`

```
In[2]: legislators = { "Tsang Yok-sing" : "DAB", "Albert Ho" : "Democratic", "Lee Cheuk-yan" : "Labour", "James To" : "Democratic", "Chan Kam-lam" : "DAB", "Lau Wong-fat" : "Economic Synergy", "Emily Lau" : "Democratic" }
In[3]: names, parties = zip(*legislators.items())
In[4]: names
Out[4]: 
('Tsang Yok-sing',
 'Emily Lau',
 'Lau Wong-fat',
 'Chan Kam-lam',
 'James To',
 'Albert Ho',
 'Lee Cheuk-yan')
In[5]: parties
Out[5]: 
('DAB',
 'Democratic',
 'Economic Synergy',
 'DAB',
 'Democratic',
 'Democratic',
 'Labour')
```